# Working with 3D arrays in Java, issues assigning an array to [0][0][x]

Tags: java, arrays, return, multidimensional-array

I'm having trouble understanding exactly why I'm encountering this problem. I'm working on a program that needs to read in a text file full of ints and assign them to a 3d integer array. I have a method that returns a single integer array and I'm trying to assign it to the "Z" of my 3d array. The call to that method is inside a for loop nested within another for loop, like so:

```
for (int currentRow = 0; currentRow < totalRows; currentRow++){
    for (int currentColumn = 0; currentColumn < totalColumns; currentColumn++){
        my3dArray[currentRow][currentColumn] = returnZ();
        System.out.print(my3dArray[currentRow][currentColumn][0]);
    }
    System.out.println("");
}
```

However, this results in every single my3dArray[x][y][0] value being equal to the very last Z[0] value that was returned. I later changed my depth return method to return just one integer (the one that is supposed to be stored at my3dArray[x][y][0]) and assign the returned value like

```
for (int currentRow = 0; currentRow < totalRows; currentRow++){
    for (intCurrentColumn = 0; currentColumn < totalColumns; currentColumn++){
        my3dArray[currentRow][currentColumn][0] = returnZ(); //changed to return int
        System.out.print(my3dArray[currentRow][currentColumn[0]);
    }
}
```

and that worked perfectly. So I know there's no issues with the array itself that's being returned. The returned depth int[] only has 2 indices, so I could just write one method to return [x][y][0] and another to return [x][y][1], but I would much rather understand what I'm doing wrong and learn from it so I know how to do it in the future.
I've had issues in the past with proper use of passing array values around, so it's probably just that

```
    my3dArray[currentRow][currentColumn] = returnDepth(); //returning int[]
```

doesn't work the way I think it does. Either that or there's some other error that I haven't noticed.

--EDIT--
I just noticed if i change that print statement to my3dArray[0][0][0], the output looks like what I'm trying to get... so it seems that the values are being assigned to the first index of each array instead of following the incrementation of the currentColumn and currentRow. I'm really starting to feel like I'm about to see an embarrassingly obvious logic error in my code, but I'm still utterly confused.

--EDIT2--

returnZ() actually takes a integer which I'm passing to it via a scanner thats taken the file like
        my3dArray[currentRow][currentColumn] = returnZ(scanner.nextInt()) 
but given that it works when returning an int, i omitted that thinking it was irrelevant.
The code for returnZ is like this:

```
returnZ(int input){
    int Z[] = new int[2];
    int value1 = input;                                 
    int value2;
    if (input%10 != 0){
        if (input%10 > 5) value2 = 1;
        if (input%10 < 5) value2 = 2;
    }
    else value2 = 0;

    Z[0] = value1;
    Z[1] = value2;
    return Z;
}
```

It probably looks really silly but there it is. (third edit, fixed some typos in that return method)

Comment: Can you post the code for `returnZ()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only part of your code that I can think of that is not working correctly how you are inputting the ints.

See this test program.

```
public class Test2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception 
    {
        int[][][] my3dArray = new int[3][3][]; 
        Random r = new Random();

        for (int currentRow = 0; currentRow < my3dArray.length; currentRow++){
            for (int currentColumn = 0; currentColumn < my3dArray[currentRow].length; currentColumn++){
                my3dArray[currentRow][currentColumn] = returnZ(r.nextInt(11));
                System.out.print(my3dArray[currentRow][currentColumn][0]);
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(my3dArray));
    }

    public static int[] returnZ(int input)
    {
        int Z[] = new int[2];
        int value1 = input;                                 
        int value2 = 0;
        if (input%10 != 0){
            if (input%10 > 5) 
                value2 = 1;
            if (input%10 < 5) 
                value2 = 2;
        }
        else 
            value2 = 0;

        Z[0] = value1;
        Z[1] = value2;
        return Z;
    }
}
```

When I run this on one instance it prints:

```
 1049
 1010
 542
 [[[10, 0], [4, 2], [9, 1]], [[1, 2], [0, 0], [10, 0]], [[5, 0], [4, 2], [2, 2]]]
```

Comment: Thanks for trying to figure it out, I'll go ahead and mark you as best answer. I still had issues with it, for some reason, so I've done something wrong somewhere. I've just created two seperate returnZ() methods that correspond to the 2 indices, so it's working, at least. I still have no idea what's wrong, but it's my fault. So thanks for the effort!